# How to Navigate between activities within a tab using TabHost in android

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-style-tabhost

I understand that TabActivity is deprected. But my situation is like I have an application built entirely using Activities - without any tabs (and no Fragments). Now, I have to add 3 tabs at the bottom of this appliation. The first tab needs to be used to perform all functionalities of existing app i.e, I need to be able to navigate between all existing activities within the 1st tab. The other 2 tabs will contain 2 new functionalities.

Can any one help me with an approach? [I am against using Fragments since I have to rewrite my application to use Fragments instead of Activities - I hope that's sensible?]

Comment: can you explain more. like in first tab you have list of activity,now what you want to do. means your tab remain in each activity.? or what?

Comment: actually i want to call one tab from the body of another tab's activity such that tabs remain in each activity...eg i have tab1,tab2,tab3.In tab1's activity(that's tab1's body) i have button which further calls another activity which is on the other hand tab2's body/activity...hope u understand what i want

Answer (score 0):

Because of Activity you have to include Tab.xml in each xml file. this  can be done smoothly by fragment. but you want 2 do through activity for that you have to make **BaseActivity** class in that TabActivity code you have to write.

->After that, Extends that BaseActivity in each Activity. in that activity you just have 2 call BaseActivity's method from each Activity for Tab Change functionality.

->Now in xml. you have to make one **Tab.xml** file which you have to **include in each activity's xml** file. so it will show in each activity..

hope this can be worked for you.